# What will be the query?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are three tables

- `Student` (STUDID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS)
- `Course` (COURSEID, COURSENAME, CREDIT)
- `Student_Course` (SCID, STUDID, COURSEID)

How to show the total credits registered by one particular student id?

Here's the details about the [tables](https://codeshare.io/21Mwpm)

Comment: update your question ad  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JOIN , SUM() and group by

```
select a.STUDID, a.NAME, sum(b.CREDIT)
from Student a 
inner join Student_Course c on a.STUDID = c.STUDID 
inner join Course b on c.COURSEID = b.COURSEID 
group by a.STUDID, a.NAME
```

Comment: thank you @scaisEdge I'm trying to do the above query in plsql function but I'm getting error can you review the code for once.... this is the [code](https://codeshare.io/5Z09og)

Comment: you should post a specific new question  .. so all the SO community can help you and not jus me ..

Comment: .  eventually comment  me the link

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785914/how-to-solve-warning-function-created-with-compilation-errors)

Comment: hey @scaisEdge can you review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852843/how-to-insert-values-from-one-table-to-another-in-pl-sql-using-trigger) it'll be very helpful one of my mate posted that...

Comment: @Ajax  .. i'm not an plsql expert anyway i have posted  a suggestion to the question in your comment above ..  hope is useful  ..