# how to solve Warning: Function created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to develop a PL/SQL functions to print total credits registered by the particular student and read the student id from the user.

this is the code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalcredit (stuid IN NUMBER)  RETURN number
IS
total number(100) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT sum(b.credit) INTO total FROM student a INNER JOIN student_course c ON a.studid = c.studid INNER JOIN course b ON c.courseid = b.courseid WHERE a.studid = stuid;
RETURN total;
END;
/
```

and [this](https://codeshare.io/21Mwpm) is the table details

Comment: Tip: line breaks are allowed in virtually any position where you can type a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the actual errors by reading them from one of the *_ERRORS views, e.g. USER_ERRORS for objects in the schema of the logged-on user, ALL_ERRORS for errors associated with objects which can be read by the current user, or DBA_ERRORS for errors associated with all objects in the database.

You can read them by using a SELECT such as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_ERRORS
  WHERE NAME = 'TOTALCREDIT'
```

Keep in mind that Oracle uses UPPER-CASE for all schema objects unless they are explicitly quoted, so you need to specify the UPPER-CASE version of the name when querying these views.

[Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1085.htm)

---

In the case of your function, it looks to me like the problem is the line which reads

```
total  number(100) := 0;
```

Oracle only supports precision of up to 38 digits. I suggest you change this to

```
total  number := 0;
```

and see how that works for you.

Best of luck.